# custom address field not showing in billing address in sales order view page admin

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout, billing

I have created custom address field using below code in my module--

```
   $installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = $this;

$entityTypeId = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer_address');
$attributeSetId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'delivery_premises_type', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'select',
    "backend" => "",
    'label' => 'Delivery Premises Type',
    "source" => "",
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '',
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique" => false,
    'source' => 'address/entity_dpt',
));

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer_address", "delivery_premises_type");
$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $attributeGroupId, 'delivery_premises_type', '999'  //sort_order
);


$used_in_forms=array(
                     'customer_address_edit',
                     'adminhtml_customer_address',
                     );

$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
;
$attribute->save();



$sales_quote_address = $installer->getTable('sales/quote_address');
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_quote_address, 'delivery_premises_type', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'comment' => 'New Delivery Premises Type Field Added'
        ));

$sales_order_address = $installer->getTable('sales/order_address');
$installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($sales_order_address, 'delivery_premises_type', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'comment' => 'New Delivery Premises Type Field Added'
        ));



$installer->endSetup();
```

and also changed in Configuration > customer Configuration > address template , I followed below links--

https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/how-to-add-custom-field-in-the-billing-and-shipping-address-of-onepage-checkout-in-magento/

https://raghunathgurjar.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/how-add-a-new-custom-field-to-customer-address/

still its not showing in sales order view page and in pdf as well.

Please help.

**EDITS-**

Here is config.xml

```
<fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <delivery_premises_type>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                    <to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address>
                </delivery_premises_type>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
            <customer_address>
                <delivery_premises_type>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </delivery_premises_type>
            </customer_address>
        </fieldsets>
```

I checked tables **'sales_flat_quote_address'** and **'sales_flat_order_address'**, there is column '**delivery_premises_type** but no values is saving in this column in both tables, if I do manual entry in this column in both tables, it works fine.
why entry is not going in both tables.

**SOLVED---**
I did mistake **in billing.phtml** file during putting my custom field on checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

In your module `config.xml` you have to write address conversion xml like :

```
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_address>
            <custom_address>
                <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
            </custom_address>
        </sales_convert_quote_address>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

Comment: Please check edits